# SQL Max Function per group

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a complex query and which may return more than one record per group. There is a field that has a numeric sequential number. If in a group there is more than one record returned I just want the record with the highest sequential number.

I’ve tried using the SQL MAX function, but if I try to add more than one field it returns all records, instead of the one with the highest sequential field in that group.

I am trying to accomplish this in MS Access.

---

Edit: 4/5/11
Trying to create a table as an example of what I am trying to do

I have the following table:

tblItemTrans

ItemID(PK)
Eventseq(PK)
ItemTypeID
UserID

Eventseq is a number field that increments for each ItemID. (Don’t ask me why, that’s how the table was created.) Each ItemID can have one or many Evenseq’s. I only need the last record (max(Eventseq)) PER each ItemTypeID.

Hope this helps any.

Comment: post your sql and you'll get better feed back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your SequentialNumber is an ID (unique across the table), then you could use

```
select *
from tbl
where seqnum in (
    select max(seqnum) from tbl
    group by groupcolumn)
```

If it is not, an alternative to Lamak's query is the Access domain function DMAX

```
select *
from tbl
where seqnum = DMAX("seqnum", "tbl", "groupcolumn='" & groupcolumn & "'")
```

Note: if the groupcolumn is a date, use `#` instead of single quotes `'` in the above, if it is a numeric, remove the single quotes.

Comment: The table has two primary keys, one being the the sequential number field. Tried the DMAX option, but it's not returning anything at all.

Comment: @Rick / for the DMAX, the 3 parts need to have the correct column name, table name, and group-column name.

Comment: the dmax instruction itself seems to be working. I tested in VBA and it returns the highest value of the field seqnum. My guess is that since the returned value is the highest of all the table it doesn't find that value in the group.

Comment: @Rick / That is why there is a 3rd part, the condition `groupcolumn=<currentgroup>` to find the max for that group

Comment: OK, I left out the second field as the edit on top. I tried using a parameter. So far seems to be working.

Comment: DMax() is a terrible solution. It has no place at all in a SQL statement.

Comment: @David / No argument any day. But Access is a toy, and if it is being used with large volumes of data (can't go beyond 2GB filesize limit), it should be an Access ADP/MSSQL system anyway.

Comment: Access/Jet/ACE is not a toy at all. As to ADPs, MS has been deprecating those in favor of MDB/ACCDB/ODBC for about five years. ADPs have not received any upgrades in the last two versions of Access and may very well be completely dropped from the next version of Access. They were always problematic (changing from version to version, with bugs stamped out in one version re-appearing in the next), particularly because of their reliance on ADO, which was really problematic in cases where you wanted to secure your data (e.g., ADO sometimes bypasses your VIEWS and goes straight to the tables).

Comment: So, no, ADPs are not a good answer. SQL Server is perfectly usable with Access when your data needs exceed the capacities of Jet/ACE, but you don't need an ADP to work with SQL Server data -- and you can use the server database of your choice (as opposed to being limited to SQL Server if you chose an ADP).

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM YourTable A
INNER JOIN (SELECT GroupColumn, MAX(SequentialColumn) MaxSeq
            FROM YourTable
            GROUP BY GroupColumn) B
ON A.GroupColumn = B.GroupColumn AND A.SequentialColumn = B.MaxSeq
```